# Unable to start Baasbox server

Tags: baasbox

Am beginning in Baasbox (http://www.baasbox.com/) and i followed the steps indicated in the video (on http://www.baasbox.com/download-page/ in bottom of the page) to install the server on windows.

The steps are downloading the server and then the SDK for your platform (iOS, Android, Javascript) and then running the server in localhost listening on port 9000.

So i followed all theses steps and downloaded the server but it does not start on the adress indicated (localhost:9000). So i went to their Faq on Google groups and searched so many times without any result and still can not start the server !!!

In the video, they say that you should already install a Java runtime environnement so i went to Oracle.com downloading the JRE even i have already java installed and working fine and i unzipped this JRE and referenced it from path variable but nothing worked !! that's what i tried and am not sure wether this is a JRE/JDK issue.

So i will be very grateful for anyone who can help me with this issue with any idea.

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

To build and run BaasBox you need a JDK (not JRE!) (version 8) and sets system variable JAVA_HOME to JDK8.

Comment: Thnx, you mean that it accepts at least the JDK8  ?? Actually i have the JDK 7 version. so i gonna install the 8 version, thnx

Comment: I have installed JDK8 and it worked fine for the first time but now it does not !! with the message error saying that the class play.core.server.NettyServer not found so i can not understand what does it have to do with the playframework (which is installed for me)

Comment: You must delete RUNNING_PID file in baasbox folder to run BaasBox again.
OR
use my custom batch
https://github.com/layerlre/startBaasBox